# Easier approach for a typical geometry problem

Tags: geometry

**Question**

> A line $OA$ of length $r$ starts from its initial position $OX$ and traces an angle $\angle AOB=\alpha$ in the anticlockwise direction. It then traces back in the clockwise direction $\angle BOC=3\theta$. L is the foot of the perpendicular from C on OA,  such that $\frac{\sin^3\theta}{CL}=\frac{\cos^3\theta}{OL}=1$.
>   Then what is the value of $\frac{1-r\cos\alpha}{r\sin\alpha}$?

**My attempt:**

Diagram: (*I tried my best in GeoGebra :(* and that $\angle AOB=\alpha\neq30^\circ$)
[image]

My approach is that $r^2=\cos^6\theta+\sin^6\theta=1-3\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$

Also, $r\sin(3\theta-\alpha)=CL=\sin^3\theta$. But now I am stuck in a dead end. I wish to expand this $\sin(3\theta-\alpha)$ (to get those $\cos\alpha$ and the $\sin\alpha$) but I am afraid doing so will be too complicated.

Is there any other approach? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I just realized that the diagram I gave above was *not* present in the original question, and that while I have drawn OC to be on the other side of OA, it can also be on the same side of OA as OB is. (as nothing is given about the position of OC and OB wrt OA in the orignial question) Though I don't think it should affect the final answer but I still noted just in case.

Comment: It seems that the value $\frac{1-r\cos\alpha}{r\sin\alpha}$ is not constant. For $\theta=30^\circ$, the value equals $\frac{7}{3\sqrt 3}$, but for $\theta=45^\circ$, the value equals $2$.

Comment: @mathlove The given answer is $\frac{1-r\cos\alpha}{r\sin\alpha}=\tan2\theta$. So, yes, it does vary with $\theta$, but this doesn't seem to match the values you have :/

Comment: Expanding $\sin(3\theta-\alpha)$ and also $\cos(3\theta-\alpha)$, one can get expressions for $r\sin\alpha$ and $r\cos\alpha$ as functions of $\theta$.

Comment: The result I get is not $\tan2\theta$, and it agrees with that given by @mathlove.

Comment: @Aretino I tried to what you say, but I couldn't separate the variables from each other and cancel them. It got too messy :(

Comment: @Aretino I am sorry but I copied the question as it was given. In such a case as both of your answers are differing, the answer given for it may have been wrong then. But I don't know how you got the other answer either :(

Comment: It seems to me that $\frac{1-r\cos\alpha}{r\sin\alpha}\not=\tan(2\theta)$. For $\theta=30^\circ,\cos\alpha=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 7},\sin\alpha=\frac{3\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 7}$, then $\frac{1-r\cos\alpha}{r\sin\alpha}=\frac{7}{3\sqrt 3}\not=\sqrt 3=\tan(2\theta)$.

Comment: @mathlove Then $\tan2\theta$ might be the wrong answer. But I still do not know how you arrived at this other answer. Please consider posting an answer, thank you!

Comment: If we assume that $\alpha\gt 3\theta$, the value does equal $\tan(2\theta)$. See the addition in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** :

If we assume that $\alpha\gt 3\theta$, then the result does equal $\tan(2\theta)$.

We have
$$\sin^3\theta=-r\sin(3\theta-\alpha)=-r\sin(3\theta)\cos\alpha+r\cos(3\theta)\sin\alpha\tag3$$
and
$$\cos^3\theta=r\cos(3\theta-\alpha)=r\cos(3\theta)\cos\alpha+r\sin(3\theta)\sin\alpha\tag4$$

$\sin(3\theta)\times (3)-\cos(3\theta)\times(4)$ gives
$$\sin^3\theta\sin(3\theta)-\cos^3\theta\cos(3\theta)=-r\sin^2(3\theta)\cos\alpha-r\cos^2(3\theta)\cos\alpha=-r\cos\alpha$$

$\cos(3\theta)\times (3)+\sin(3\theta)\times(4)$ gives
$$\sin^3\theta\cos(3\theta)+\cos^3\theta\sin(3\theta)=r\cos^2(3\theta)\sin\alpha+r\sin^2(3\theta)\sin\alpha=r\sin\alpha$$

It follows from these that, writing $s:=\sin\theta$ and $c:=\cos\theta$, 
$$\begin{align}\frac{1-r\cos\alpha}{r\sin\alpha}&=\frac{1+\sin^3\theta\sin(3\theta)-\cos^3\theta\cos(3\theta)}{\sin^3\theta\cos(3\theta)+\cos^3\theta\sin(3\theta)}\\\\&=\frac{1+s^3(3s-4s^3)-c^3(4c^3-3c)}{s^3(4c^3-3c)+c^3(3s-4s^3)}\\\\&=\frac{-4(s^6+c^6)+3(s^4+c^4)+1}{3cs(-s^2+c^2)}\\\\&=\frac{-4((s^2+c^2)^3-3s^4c^2-3s^2c^4)+3((s^2+c^2)^2-2s^2c^2)+1}{3cs(c^2-s^2)}\\\\&=\frac{-4+12c^2s^2+3-6s^2c^2+1}{3cs(c^2-s^2)}\\\\&=\frac{2cs}{c^2-s^2}\\\\&=\tan(2\theta)\end{align}$$

---

*Too long for a comment*.

In the following, we assume that $3\theta\gt\alpha$.

We have
$$\sin^3\theta=r\sin(3\theta-\alpha)=r\sin(3\theta)\cos\alpha-r\cos(3\theta)\sin\alpha\tag1$$
and
$$\cos^3\theta=r\cos(3\theta-\alpha)=r\cos(3\theta)\cos\alpha+r\sin(3\theta)\sin\alpha\tag2$$

$\sin(3\theta)\times (1)+\cos(3\theta)\times(2)$ gives
$$\sin^3\theta\sin(3\theta)+\cos^3\theta\cos(3\theta)=r\sin^2(3\theta)\cos\alpha+r\cos^2(3\theta)\cos\alpha=r\cos\alpha$$

$-\cos(3\theta)\times (1)+\sin(3\theta)\times(2)$ gives
$$-\sin^3\theta\cos(3\theta)+\cos^3\theta\sin(3\theta)=r\cos^2(3\theta)\sin\alpha+r\sin^2(3\theta)\sin\alpha=r\sin\alpha$$

It follows from these that, writing $s:=\sin\theta$ and $c:=\cos\theta$, 
$$\begin{align}\frac{1-r\cos\alpha}{r\sin\alpha}&=\frac{1-(\sin^3\theta\sin(3\theta)+\cos^3\theta\cos(3\theta))}{-\sin^3\theta\cos(3\theta)+\cos^3\theta\sin(3\theta)}\\\\&=\frac{1-s^3(3s-4s^3)-c^3(4c^3-3c)}{-s^3(4c^3-3c)+c^3(3s-4s^3)}\\\\&=\frac{4(s^6-c^6)-3(s^4-c^4)+1}{-8s^3c^3+3cs(s^2+c^2)}\\\\&=\frac{4(s-c)(s^2+sc+c^2)(s+c)(s^2-sc+c^2)-3(s^2+c^2)(s^2-c^2)+1}{-8s^3c^3+3cs}\\\\&=\frac{4(s-c)(1+sc)(s+c)(1-sc)-3(s^2-c^2)+1}{sc(3-8s^2c^2)}\\\\&=\frac{4(s^2-c^2)(1-s^2c^2)-3(s^2-c^2)+1}{sc(3-8s^2c^2)}\\\\&=\frac{(c^2-s^2)(4s^2c^2-1)+1}{sc(3-8s^2c^2)}\\\\&=\frac{-(\cos2\theta)(1-\sin2\theta)(1+\sin2\theta)+1}{sc(4(1-2s^2c^2)-1)}\\\\&=\frac{-\cos^32\theta+1}{sc(4(s-c)^2-1)}\\\\&=\frac{2-2\cos^3(2\theta)}{\sin(2\theta)(3-2\sin^2(2\theta))}\\\\&=\frac{\frac{2}{\cos^3(2\theta)}-2}{\frac{3\tan(2\theta)}{\cos^2(2\theta)}-2\tan^3(2\theta)}\\\\&=\frac{\frac{2}{\cos(2\theta)}(1+\tan^2(2\theta))-2}{3\tan(2\theta)(1+\tan^2(2\theta))-2\tan^3(2\theta)}\\\\&=\frac{-2+\frac{2}{\cos(2\theta)}+\frac{2}{\cos(2\theta)}\tan^2(2\theta)}{\tan^3(2\theta)+3\tan(2\theta)}\\\\&=\frac{-2\cos(2\theta)+2+2\tan^2(2\theta)}{\sin(2\theta)(\tan^2(2\theta)+3)}\end{align}$$
It seems that this is not equal to $\tan(2\theta)$.

Comment: Wow, this was way too complex than I thought! This question appeared in a test with 60 minutes for 30 questions. I'm surprised they put such a question there :-O

Comment: I simplified your final expression a bit. Unfortunately, I could not simplify it further than the last step. I hope you can try and make it a bit simpler. Thanks! (PS: I ruined your formatting as well, sorry idk how to fix it :( )

Comment: The result can be also written as $${1-\cos^32\theta\over(3/2)\sin2\theta-\sin^32\theta}.$$

Comment: @GaurangTandon: I added some steps trying to use $\tan(2\theta)$ and fixed them.

Comment: @Aretino: Yes, I've tried to use $\tan(2\theta)$, but the result I've got is not simple.

Comment: Alright then. I'll accept the sad truth that this question's answer turned out to be really bad  :(

Comment: There's still some hope :D Thanks! But, at what step did you use the fact that $\alpha>\tan3\theta$ in your new derivation?

Comment: @Gaurang Tandon: What I used is $\alpha\gt 3\theta$, not $\alpha\gt \tan(3\theta)$. I used $\alpha\gt 3\theta$ at the step where $\sin^3\theta=-r\sin(3\theta-\alpha)$ which is $(3)$. In fact, when $\alpha\gt 3\theta$, we have $\sin^3\theta=r\sin(\alpha-3\theta)$ which is $(3)$ and $\cos^3\theta=r\cos(\alpha-3\theta)$ which is $(4)$. These are different from $\sin^3\theta=r\sin(3\theta-\alpha)$ which is $(1)$ and $\cos^3\theta=r\cos(3\theta-\alpha)$ which is $(2)$. More concreatly, $(3)$ is different from $(1)$ (since $\sin x=-\sin(-x)$), but $(4)$ is the same as $(2)$ since $\cos x=\cos(-x)$.